# Is there a basic template I can use to create POCOs from a Db by MyGeneration?

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation, poco, mygeneration

What is the main code template used in common with MyGeneration when it comes to creating POCOS from a Db schema?

Basically I want to have classes without any behavior; just properties (collections properly defined based on the associations in Db).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be hard to modify the dOODads entity template to just generate the classes. Out of the box it's already pretty much right, just generating a simple class. There is some custom behaviour but any tweaks required would be pretty minor.

Generating the related collections/objects would be the only significant work required. There are [samples in the MyGeneration Template library](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/TemplateLibrary/Template/?id=dd9bdb5c-26b1-4029-a643-74b4ee437e7a) that demonstrate collecting related objects.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [.netTiers](http://nettiers.com/default.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) application framework using CodeSmith Generator. This creates domain objects using the tables. It can create DAL's and much more.